# Is Grapher able to display values in the x-axis as (π/2), (π), (3π/2), (2π) rather than 1,57, 3,14, 4,71, 6,28 (and so on.. )?

Tags: grapher

As title says....
Is Grapher able to display values in the x-axis as
(π/2), (π), (3π/2), (2π) rather than 1,57, 3,14, 4,71, 6,28 ?(and so on.. ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the axis and choose π from Units.